# Ненулевая цифра факториала. Код не проходит проверку на время

Tags: python

Мой код не проходит проверку на время. Нужно уложиться в 0.2 секунды, но в итоге 6 из 20 тестов, мой код превышает лимит времени.
Даже если я меняю его без использования модуля math, с помощью цикла for, либо же рекурсии, все равно не проходит

```
import math
    n=int(input())
    a=math.factorial(n)
    f=a%10
    while f==0:
        a=a//10
        f=a%10
    print(f)
```

Единственный код который проходит тест по времени приведен ниже. Но этот код писал не я, поэтому я не особо понимаю логику действий, и тот кто написал его, тоже не в силах объяснить

```
n = int(input())
m = 0
f = 1
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    while i % 2 == 0:
        i //= 2
        m += 1
    while i % 5 == 0:
        i //= 5
        m -= 1
    f = f * i % 10
f = (f << m) % 10
print(f)
```

Я хотел бы разобраться со вторым кодом и понять алгоритм(имею ввиду к чему там остаток от деления на 2, на 5 и на 10), либо ускорить первый код, что бы он прошел тест по времени, если это возможно. Если кто то может помочь с чем либо из этого, буду благодарен!

Суть самой задачи: напишите программу определения последней ненулевой цифры факториала

Входные данные: Задано число n(1<=n<=32767)

Ограничение по времени 0.2 сек

Ограничение по памяти 64мб

Comment: А добавьте в вопрос формулировку задачи? Если это вопрос "последняя цифра факториала числа" - то там идут 1, 2, 6, 4, а потом - сплошные нули

Comment: @S.H. добавил. задача найти последнюю ненулевую цифру факториала

Comment: Какие ограничения? Разве трудно привести полную формулировку задачи?

Comment: Ну, самая главная подксказка - не вычислять сам факториал! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Странно, что автор не может объяснить код, потому что код толковый.

Если на пальцах, то двойки из множителей факториала расходуются на две цели - часть на образование конечных нулей вместе с пятерками, и часть на формирование ненулевой части.

Переменная `m` - это баланс - насколько вторых двоек больше. Каждое число, содержащее множитель-пятерку, отбирает одну двойку (если содержит 25 - то две двойки и так далее).

В конце выполняется умножение на 2^m через сдвиг, чтобы учесть неизрасходованные двойки, и последняя цифра результата получается через оператор модуля %10 - ну это основы языка, а не алгоритмические хитрости.