# Как убрать проблему Программа выполнялась слишком долго и была прервана

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я новичок в Python. У меня есть программа:

```
def flt(s):
   import math
   w=math.factorial(s)
   d=int(str(w).replace('0',''))
   return d%10
s=int(input())
print(flt(s))
```

Но на платформе Сириус пишет что программа выполнялась слишком долго и была прервана. Как убрать эту проблему?

Comment: Если вы ищете младшую ненулевую цифру факториала, то можно и нужно сделать без вычисления факториала целиком. Тогда программа уложится в ограничения.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1266963/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F